# Null Pointer Exception in Facebook Login using Parse android

Tags: parse-platform, authentication, facebook-android-sdk

Null Pointer Exception occurs on loginreadsubmission....

```
public void btnfacebook(View view) {
     ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permission, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {

            } else if (user.isNew()) {

            } else {
                Toaster.show(getApplicationContext(),"YES");
            }
        }
      });
  }
```

permission variable:

```
List<String> permission = permission = Arrays.asList("email");
```

Please Help !!!